# D3 JS append a new text box with 3 new key value pairs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am new to D3 JS and I am struggling to make a suitable solution for my problem.

I would to add a new set of data from a seperate dataset variable into a chart. With upto 5 values and on a seperate line.

After removing the coloured rectangles and legend names, I would like the new values to sit in the middle where the previous legend was before.

```
var dataset = [
{ name: 'IE', percent: 39.10 },
{ name: 'Chrome', percent: 32.51 },
{ name: 'Safari', percent: 13.68 },
{ name: 'Firefox', percent: 8.71 },
{ name: 'Others', percent: 6.01 }
];

var pie=d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d){return d.percent})
  .sort(null)
  .padAngle(.03);

var w=300,h=300;

var outerRadius=w/2;
var innerRadius=100;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var arc=d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
  .innerRadius(innerRadius);

var svg=d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr({
      width:w,
      height:h,
      class:'shadow'
  }).append('g')
  .attr({
      transform:'translate('+w/2+','+h/2+')'
  });
var path=svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr({
      d:arc,
  fill:function(d,i){
      return color(d.data.name);
  }
  });

path.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attrTween('d', function(d) {
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, d);
      return function(t) {
          return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
  });


var restOfTheData=function(){
    var text=svg.selectAll('text')
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("dy", ".4em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d){
            return d.data.percent+"%";
        })
        .style({
            fill:'#fff',
            'font-size':'10px'
        });

    var legendRectSize=20;
    var legendSpacing=7;
    var legendHeight=legendRectSize+legendSpacing;


    var legend=svg.selectAll('.legend')
        .data(color.domain())
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr({
            class:'legend',
            transform:function(d,i){
                //Just a calculation for x & y position
                return 'translate(-35,' + ((i*legendHeight)-65) + ')';
            }
        });
    legend.append('rect')
        .attr({
            width:legendRectSize,
            height:legendRectSize,
            rx:20,
            ry:20
        })
        .style({
            fill:color,
            stroke:color
        });

    legend.append('text')
        .attr({
            x:30,
            y:15
        })
        .text(function(d){
            return d;
        }).style({
            fill:'#929DAF',
            'font-size':'14px'
        });
};

setTimeout(restOfTheData,1000);
```

This is the code from the site:

http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/d3-js/create-a-simple-donut-chart-using-d3-js/

Answer (score 0):

The original dataset is found at the top of the file:

```
var dataset = [
        { name: 'IE', percent: 39.10 },
        { name: 'Chrome', percent: 32.51 },
        { name: 'Safari', percent: 13.68 },
        { name: 'Firefox', percent: 8.71 },
        { name: 'Others', percent: 6.01 }
];
```

You can modify it this way, by simply adding in your data (notice I changed the names and values). This piece of code will support as many lines as you want, although do bear in mind it does not implement calculating percentages, so you'll want to keep the sum of values to `100`.

```
var dataset = [
        { name: 'foo', percent: 59 },
        { name: 'bar', percent: 31 },
        { name: 'lorem', percent: 8 },
        { name: 'ipsum', percent: 2 }
    ];
```

Here is a fork of the original codepen implementing this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRxjxo